# Random failure in TestNG + Selenium

Tags: java, testing, selenium-webdriver, testng

I am trying to test cases with TestNG + Selenium. I checked it with IE, Firefox and Chrome browser. Some time Firefox and Chrome passes my test cases where as IE gives errors like "Xpath not found" or "element is not clickable".

Another issue is that when I run case by case (1 test case at a time) then it passes and when I run bunch or all of them (around 50) then it fails some test cases, which already passed in the one by one run.

I want to run my test cases with all the above mentioned browsers.

Please help me regarding this.

Comment: Is the element is ovelapping with some other element in IE? it happens  in some cases like `appmenu`. if yes then add `scrollIntoView` javascript to that element.

Comment: No.. There is no overlapping text.

Comment: When I run all these test cases using my TestRunner file which runs all test cases at that time some test cases skipped also. I dont have any idea why this is happening. I am not using any dependency or etc. please help me